# CSS-Specifity and CSS Inheritance (concrete question)?

Tags: css

i would by thankful for an official link (and section) of the specification for CSS, that explains if:

```
.one two h1 {color:green;font-family:arial;}  /*case 1 */
.one two h1 {color:blue;}   /*case 2*/
```

will result in (when evaluated by the browser)

```
.one two h1 {color:blue;font-family:arial;}  /*case 3*/
```

or will it be:

```
.one two h1 {color:blue;}  /*case 4*/
```

==>I have read a lot about inheritance, specifity, cascading etc but I still have not found for the given example which rules apply here.

In regard to specifity, both elements are equal in specifity: However the case2 will "win" as it is equal specific but the last(!!) one declared (=most specific). 
But does specifity always apply to the whole selector with ALL properties defined. Or only to the properties that are in "competition" (and declared in both).

thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be `.one two h1 {color:blue;font-family:arial;}  /*case 3*/`

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order

"Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself. "

Answer (score 1):

It will be:

```
.one two h1 {color:blue;font-family:arial;}  /*case 3*/
```

The later rules override previous CSS properties one by one.